# Convert millisecond to 24 hours format?

Tags: java, android

The below code will convert it to 12 hours format. How do I get a 24 hours format?

```
String time = cursorInbox.getString(indexDateInbox);
Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(time);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String _date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Use "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Comment: Thanks, @Brans I didn't notice HH

Comment: Notice the capitalized "HH"!! you are using "hh"

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the 24 hr format you must to use the format pattern "HH" instead of "hh". So that your format code would look like this "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS". Notice the capitalized "HH" in the hours position.

For further formatting patterns look at this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html